# Why can't Rails locate gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

I installed the geocoder gem in my gemfile like this:

`gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.5.1'`

Then I added this line to my model

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord 
  geocoded_by :address
end
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `geocoded_by' for #<Class:0x00007f8b58b763b8>
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error? I figured installing the gem would be enough, but apparently, Rails can't locate the Geocoder library.

**UPDATE #1** Here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'impressionist', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**UPDATE #2** 
When I run `gem list geocoder`, This is what outputs:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

geocoder (default: 1.5.1, 1.4.8, 1.4.7)
```

**UPDATE #3** I don't think it's just geocoder...

I added this to my gemfile:

```
group :development do
  # other gems are here, they're just not listed.
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end
```

However, I'm still getting regular errors. So now, not even the better gems error is being found!!!

**UPDATE #4** Adding my Place Model and application record

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  geocoded_by :address
end

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

**UPDATE #5** Github issues recommendation

It was recommended to add this at the top of my model file:

```
extend Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord
```

This was sort of a work-around solution, but not even this worked!

I get this error: `uninitialized constant Place::Geocoder`

**UPDATE #6 | Temporary Fix**

I downgraded `gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.5.1'` to `gem 'geocoder', '1.5'`

Any ideas?

Comment: After running `bundle install` did you restart the server?

Comment: @Emmanuel Yes, I did restart the server.

Comment: Are you sure the gem is loaded into your current environment? It is possible that its included in some specific segment such as development or test.

Comment: @Vasanth It is not in any `:develpment` or `:test` block. I'll add my gemfile above.

Comment: what happens when you type in terminal `gem list geocoder` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Let me update my post with that information.

Comment: Try putting the gem higher up, maybe right after the rails gem.

Comment: @dan-klasson I just tried that; I got the same error :/

Comment: You should post it here: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/1178

Comment: Can you show content of ApplicationRecord please?

Comment: @DennyMueller Okay, I just updated my post with my model

Comment: unfortunately not what I was looking for :) `application_record.rb` is what I am looking for. Especially the top part with the `class ApplicationRecord < ....`

Comment: @DennyMueller Oops sorry, let me add it.

Comment: mhmh thanks... I was hopeing that you used `ActiveRecord::API` instead of `Base`. Then the fix would have been easy. What you could try at least for debugging is to add `extend ::Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord` before the `self.abstract_class` in the application_record.rb and see if it works then. Ohhh there came an edit. use the double colon before `Geocoder`

Comment: @DennyMueller I tried extending `::Geocoder::Model::ActiveRecord` But when I do that, I get this error: `uninitialized constant Geocoder`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189744/discussion-between-denny-mueller-and-angel-garcia).

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using? Any messages printed out when running `bundle install`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that necessary to do 
`bundle update` .Always that you add gem in your Gemfile is necessary to do this.

Comment: Yeah, the bundle update didn’t work. In fact the opposite was true, I had to go down a version for the gem to work. The most recent version of the gem wasn’t working. As for the better errors gem, bundle updating didn’t fix it.